# Query em 2 tabelas que tem colunas com o mesmo nome

Tags: sql-server, join

Bom dia, tenho duas tabelas que tem a coluna "st", quando puxo as informações vem o st da tabela "registros", gostaria de puxar o "st" da tabela "configuracao".

```
sql = "SELECT *   FROM configuracao b   LEFT JOIN dividas a on (b.registro = a.registro) and (b.empresa='" & Left(Combo1.Text, 2) & "')  left JOIN registros r on (b.registro = r.registro) and (b.empresa='" & Left(Combo1.Text, 2) & "')  ORDER BY r.data"


        While Not (rsconf.EOF)
              If (MSFlexGrid2.TextMatrix(li - 1, 0) = Left(rsconf("data"), 4)) And (ln > 1) Then li = li - 1
                            If rsconf("registro") <> "" Then Text1.Text = rsconf("registro")
                            If rsconf("nome") <> "" Then Label4.Caption = Trim(rsconf("nome"))
                            If rsconf("dt_adm") <> "" Then Label5.Caption = data_Normal(rsconf("dt_adm"))
                            If rsconf("st") <> "" Then
                                  MSFlexGrid1.TextMatrix(ln, 2) = "PENDÊNCIA"
                                  If rsconf("st") = "PA" Then MSFlexGrid1.TextMatrix(ln, 2) = "PARCELADO"
                            End If
                            If rsconf("dt_dem") <> "" Then Label7.Caption = data_Normal(rsconf("dt_dem"))
                            If rsconf("pag") <> "" Then
                               Label8.Caption = "NÃO"
                                If rsconf("pag") = "S" Then Label8.Caption = "SIM"
                            End If
                            v_dt = 0
                            If rsconf("data") <> "" Then v_dt = Mid(data_Normal(rsconf("data")), 4, 2)
                            Call encontra_mes
                            If rsconf("data") <> "" Then MSFlexGrid1.TextMatrix(ln, 0) = data_Normal(rsconf("data"))
                            If rsconf("valor") <> "" Then
                                  MSFlexGrid1.TextMatrix(ln, 1) = Format(rsconf("valor"), "#,##0.00")
                                If MSFlexGrid2.TextMatrix(li, cn) = "" Then
                                      MSFlexGrid2.TextMatrix(li, cn) = Format(rsconf("valor"), "#,##0.00")
                                Else
                                  MSFlexGrid2.TextMatrix(li, cn) = Format(CDbl(MSFlexGrid2.TextMatrix(li, cn)) + CDbl(rsconf("valor")), "#,##0.00")
                                End If
                                  v_ano = Left(rsconf("data"), 4)
                                  MSFlexGrid2.TextMatrix(li, 0) = v_ano
                            End If
                            If rsconf("valor_divida") <> "" Then v_td = Format(rsconf("valor_divida"), "#,##0.00")
                      ln = ln + 1
                      li = li + 1
                        rsconf.MoveNext
                        MSFlexGrid1.Rows = ln + 1
                        MSFlexGrid2.Rows = li + 1
                    Wend
```

Comment: Sem ver a query é muito difícil de responder além de não saber o que tem em cada *recordset*, mas na query já tentou usar `configura.st`?

Comment: Pensei ter colocado o query, desculpa ^^'

Comment: Tens a estrutura da tabela para colocar?

Comment: "configuracao" - > empresa/registro/nome/dt_adm/st/dt_dem/pag/usuario/dtu
"registros" -> empresa/registro/data/valor/usuario/dtu
"divida" -> empresa/registro/valor_divida/usuario/dtu

Comment: `select *` vai trazer todas as colunas, o correto seria você nomear corretamente as colunas e somente o que deseja, por exemplo `select configuracao.st, configuracao.registro.. from`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando se usa JOINs é bom que se dê nome aos bois e não utilizar *, pois isso pode trazer duplicidade de informação e confusão como essa sua dúvida.

Imagino que no seu Result deva ter dois campos ST e ST1 pois o SQL vai renomear quando encontrar mais de um campo com o mesmo nome

Vi que você tem a verificação da Empresa nos joins, o ideal seria colocar no Where pois eles estão verificando a tabela principal "configuracao"

Dessa forma sele select seria mais ou menos assim

```
sql = "SELECT b.st, 'outros campos'   FROM configuracao b   
LEFT JOIN dividas a on (b.registro = a.registro)  
left JOIN registros r on (b.registro = r.registro)
where  (b.empresa='" & Left(Combo1.Text, 2) & "')
ORDER BY r.data"
```

Veja que estou trazendo o ST da tabela B e não da R

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, vou tentar dessa forma.
Já ja dou um feedback do resultado.

Comment: @RodrigoMerce conseguiu resolver o problema? Se foi a partir esta resposta, vale a pena marcá-la como aceita ([por que aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)).